# AutoComplete for JQuery for multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the example code on this location http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ can I use it for multiple textboxes?

For example I have tb1, tb2 and tb3 how can I use the same script for all three?

I'm new to JQuery and I would appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
$( "#tags, #tags2, #tags3" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8fg7/

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".auto-complete-tbx").autocomplete();
    });
</script>

<input type="text" class="auto-complete-tbx" id="tb1" />
<input type="text" class="auto-complete-tbx" id="tb2" />
<input type="text" class="auto-complete-tbx" id="tb3" />
```

Comment: Do you mind marking this the answer if that is what it was for you, an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the , "comma" to seperate multiple inputs and give them options all at once like

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$("#inputid1, #inputId2, #inputid3").autocomplete({
source: availableTags ;
}):
});
</script>
```